# messed up system after offline package installation for WLAN driver

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 on my old desktop pc. Since I moved, I had no internet connection, but could use the WLAN of my neighbors. For that, I had to install an old FRITZ! USB WLAN driver. I did that by downloading a bunch of required packages via a WLAN capable notebook, copied the deb-files to the pc and installed them via

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Here are the packages that I installed during the offline installation:

- ndiswrapper-common_1.59-2_all.deb
- ndiswrapper-dkms_1.59-2_all.deb
- ndiswrapper-source_1.59-2_all.deb
- ndiswrapper-utils-1.9_1.59-2+b1_i386.deb

and the packages that I additionally installed to solve dependency problems:

- dpkg-dev_1.17.24_all.deb
- po-debconf_1.0.16+nmu3_all.deb
- module-assistant_0.11.7_all.deb
- html2text_1.3.2a-18_i386.deb
- libdpkg-perl_1.17.24_all.deb
- libstdc++6_4.9.2-10_i386.deb
- gcc-4.9-base_4.9.2-10_i386.deb

The WLAN-driver worked. The problem is, I installed package versions, that are newer than the current Ubuntu packages. Since then, I can't get updates anymore due to a broken package (libgcc1).

Now, I have a wired LAN connection again and I want to fix the problem. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

apt wants to remove a bunch of packages and I get the message "You are about to do something potentially harmful"... This is not what I want to do ;)

All I want to do is to get my old system back, which means all packages in the current Ubuntu version (trusty-updates).  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I solved my problem by means of the following steps

1. I checked the synaptic package managing tool for the installed and available versions regarding the mentioned packages
2. I then downloaded the versions tagged with (trusty) or whenever a (trusty-updates)-version was mentioned the trusty-updates version. The command was `sudo apt-get download ndiswrapper-dkms=1.59-2 ndiswrapper-source=1.59-2 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9=1.59-2 dpkg-dev=1.17.5ubuntu5.3 po-debconf=1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1 module-assistant=0.11.6 html2text=1.3.2a-17 libdpkg-perl=1.17.5ubuntu5.3 libstdc++6=4.8.2-19ubuntu1 gcc-4.9-base=4.9.1-0ubuntu1` The files could then be found in the current working directory, which in my case was the home-folder
3. Then I installed the downloaded packages with `sudo dpkg --force-all -i /CurrentWorkingDirectory/*.deb`

Everything works again :)